# Programmatically change post visibility on save_post action return a 500

Tags: custom-post-types, post-status, wp-update-post

I'm trying to change the post visibility for my custom post type. On the edit.php screen the user can use a custom field to set the post type to normal or extended. That field shall work as abstraction for the post_status. However, running the following code inside the `save_post action` terminates as `500 Internal Server Error`:

```
add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_meta_box' ), 10, 2 );
[...]
public function save_meta_box( $post_id, $post ) {
    [...]
    if( isset( $_POST['options'] ) ) {
        myplugin_set_options( $post_id, $_POST['options'] );

        // switch post visibility
        switch ( $_POST['options']['type'] ) {
            case 'normal':
                wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $post_id, 'post_status' => 'private' ));
                break;
            case 'extended':
                wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $post_id, 'post_status' => 'publish' ));
                break;
        }
    }
```

Running this code in the `load-post.php` does work fine. But I just want to set the visibility on saving not every time the post is opened. Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Watch out for recursive loops! That can happen when you call `wp_update_post()` inside the `save_post` hook. The `remove_action()` function will help you here.

Comment: Sounds plausibly. So just calling remove_action( 'save_post', 'save_meta_box' ); at the end of my save_meta_box function should work? Does not seem like.

Comment: Try `remove_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_meta_box' ) );` since the callback is a class method.

Comment: -.- Thanks for to pick up the lost path for me! Please write a answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some information about this problem in the [Action Reference for save post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post#Avoiding_infinite_loops):

> If you are calling a function such as wp_update_post that includes the save_post hook, your hooked function will create an infinite loop. To avoid this, unhook your function before calling the function you need, then re-hook it afterward.

So something like this should work:

```
[...]
add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_meta_box' ), 13, 2 );
[...]
public function save_meta_box( $post_id, $post ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['options'] ) ) {
        myplugin_set_options( $post_id, $_POST['options'] );

        remove_action( 'save_post',  array( $this, 'save_meta_box' ), 13, 2 );

        // switch post visibility
        switch ( $_POST['options']['type'] ) {
            case 'normal':
                wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $post_id, 'post_status' => 'private' ));
                break;
            case 'extended':
                wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $post_id, 'post_status' => 'publish' ));
                break;
        }

        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_meta_box' ), 13, 2 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Also worth noting that you need to pay attention to the priority you are using to hook and unhook your `'save_post'` action. Here is a great resource on this by [Tom McFarlin](https://tommcfarlin.com/update-post-in-save-post-action/)